# Flutter Google Login not Getting Registered in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, facebook-login, google-signin

## 1. The Problem

I'm trying to implement simple Facebook and Google Sign-in buttons with Firebase and Flutter, however the Google version is acting very weird. When I print the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` I either get errors or prior Facebook login data.

When I login with Facebook, my account *does* appear on Firebase, however, the Google login seems to do nothing.

Is this something I messed up in the code below or some incompatibility problem with AndroidX with parts of these libraries? Something else?

Also, it is not very clear to me if I have to put the `Project public-facing name` somewhere inside my project to make the integration with Firebase work (I had to do something similar to setup the Facebook Login button).

## 2. The Facebook Login

I had to replace `logInWithReadPermissions` with `signInWithCredential` because recent versions have changed their API. I've also tried to use previous versions of the packages, but encountered many errors (probably due to AndroidX):

```dart
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithFacebook () async {
  final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
  final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);

  if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn){
    final FacebookAccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken;
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: accessToken.token,
    );

    AuthResult signInResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

    FirebaseUser fbUser = signInResult.user;
    return fbUser;
  }
  else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

## 3. The Google Login

Again, `signInWithCredential` seems to be the more recent API:

```dart
Future<FirebaseUser> _loginWithGoogle () async{
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );
  AuthResult signInResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  final FirebaseUser user = signInResult.user;

  print(user);

  return user;
}
```

### Edit

I've tried it on an Android 9.0 (Pie) emulator and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Apparently this all worked after I added the `SHA-1` from my development environment to Firebase. I don't know why this wasn't covered in the many tutorials I watched, maybe it's a recent thing?

Comment: The part where I get Facebook data even though I logged in with Google is due to not signing out properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, my authentication code was correct for both Google and Facebook, considering the most up-to-date API.

However I needed to integrate a `SHA1 Fingerprint` to my Firebase environment, which is something I didn't realize I needed to do because none of the tutorials I followed mentioned it and it can be easily dismissed when enabling the Google Sign-in method inside Firebase.

Anyway, here are the steps you will need to complete to get the `SHA1 Fingerprint`:

1. Open Command Prompt and `cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin`.
2. Get the `SHA1` key:

   ```
   keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
   ```
3. Go to `Firebase Console > Project settings > Add Key` and add the key.