# A working login screen in Flutter using Google SignIn, but user data is not showing in my Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

As mentioned in the heading, I am successfully able to use the Google SignIn. But the user data is not showing in the Firebase Console.

```dart
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

Comment: If you have successfully signed in, the user should be listed in your Firebase Console's AUthentication tab. Does it really not appear there?

Comment: Nopes , what might /can be wrong? Asked you , coz you were having a similar issue a while ago

Comment: Was I? I don't remember... When I did manage to sign a profile in in the past, it would always appear on the console as far as I know. Could you link the issue here? It's important for other users also, because they would have more info and context about the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58442052/13189522

Comment: Ever since I learned that I had to register the SHA1 key, which is mentioned in the answer, I haven't had any problems. So I don't know if I can help much here if you're already doing that... I guess you're gonna have to wait for someone else. If the problem persists, it's probably something related to Firebase then; and, maybe, posting an issue on their Github repo migh be of help.

Comment: Okay!  I will try you code once before posting on GitHub